# Fire event during a transition

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Is there a way to fire an event when the transition is in a certain state? For example, In the code below, I have a text block that scrolls across the screen. When the text block reaches a certain x coordinate I would like an event to be triggered (i.e. Highlight the text).

Is there a way to do this with transitions, or whats the best way to accomplish something like that?

```
Player.e.select('#activeTranscript')
            .transition()
            .each(function(d, i) {
                var test = 'test';
            })
            .ease('linear')
            .duration(function() {
                return Player.active_transcript.length * 500;
            })
            .attr('x', function(){
                return  -this.clientWidth;
            });
```

Comment: To improve your chance of getting answers try to include more info. I would probably be able to answer this if you pointed me to the library documentation you used to make what you have so far. I looked up d3.js because it is a tag you used but that was pretty broad.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how long it will take for your text to reach the x coordinate, you can just have your function fire then w/ a setTimeout or d3.timer.

To get exact control over firing events during a transition, you'll have to get your hands a little dirty with attrTween and a custom interpolation:

```
  .transition().duration(3000)
    .attrTween('y', function(d, i, a){
      var interpolator = d3.interpolate(a, 400);
      var halfWayDone = false;
      return function(t){
        if (t > .5 && !halfWayDone){
          d3.select('body').append('div').text('halfway done at ' + t);
          halfWayDone = true;
        }
        return interpolator(t);
      }
    })
```

http://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/7800813